# c# compile time string hash to enum

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible in C# to hash a string at compile time and assign the integer hash value to an enum value ? Something like this:

```
enum Things {
    First  = Hash32("hello"),
    Second = Hash32("world")
}
```

Comment: This seems like an XY Problem.  Rather than ask about how to assign a string hash to an enum you should explain what problem you are trying to solve by doing this in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. We can't do this. The values we assign to the named constants should be  constants (of integral numeric type).

For more info, please have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum), in which you will also read:

> By default, the associated constant values of enum members are of type int; they start with zero and increase by one following the definition text order. You can explicitly specify any other integral numeric type as an underlying type of an enumeration type. You can also explicitly specify the associated constant values

Answer (score 0):

As @Christos states in his answer, it's not possible using the method described.  That said, there are plenty of examples of auto-generated C# code that could be performed as some kind of a pre-build step that generates a .cs file with the hashed values which could then be used by the rest of the code-base.